# Using Interfaces in Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, interface

I usually create an external class library for my ASP.NET projects, i reference it to the project i am working on then on any one of the webforms i create an object of that class and access its properties and methods from the code behind like so:

```
User usr = new User();
usr.Username = "Username";
usr.Password = "Password";
usr.Register();
```

I am currently working with a colleague of mine who calls that ' bad design" especially when I generate the class diagrams for him.  According to him he says it is "poor design/programming to instantiate objects directly in code behind file of a webform.  He says I should use interfaces instead, that way if a change is made to the class library my application wouldn't complain about any errors on the front end, meaning i would not have to change anything on the front end. eg. If i change "public string Username" to "public string User" it should not give me any errors on the front end, something about code independency or something like that.  So:

```
Interface IU = new User();
IU.Username = "Username";
IU.Password = "Password";
IU.Register();
```

That is to my own understanding, however I would like someone to verify and clarify this.

Comment: Winforms are not a part of ASP.NET. Misleading Title there. Both your code examples has you instantiating a class in the code behind. He may be referring to the use of a factory pattern or IOC container. Certainly the reference to him asking you to use interfaces would also suggest that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out to me, i missed that.  I have corrected the title.

Answer (score 2):

This is always going to be a matter of opinion and best practices.

Personally I don't see any point in creating interfaces for your domain objects (with the obvious exception of it acting as a common contract between two domain objects).

Where interfaces are very useful is between layers. Rather than creating an interface representing IUser I would declare an interface for the Register method.

This is where there's a change in design. You're declaring your register method as part of the User itself. This is a common pattern known as Active Record. Personally I don't like this approach for a few reasons:

- It puts data access code in your domain objects (and therefore all the way through your solution)
- It often requires every part of your solution to reference every other.

My suggestion would be to have a User class which is then passed into a business logic class with a Register() method. This business logic class would then implement IManagerUsers (or whatever you wish to call it).

```
public class User
{
  public string Username{get;set;}
  public string Password{get;set;}
}

public interface IUserManager
{
  bool Register(User user);
}

public class UserManager : IUserManager
{
  public bool Register(User user)
  {
    // register your user here
  }
}
```

Comment: In your example won't that mean that i will have to instantiate the UserManager class on the code behind of the webform? Or do i implement the interface itself directly on the webform itself since it is a partial class?

Comment: I would implement the interface on a new UserManager class, keep your UI code in your code behind and have another one for managing your users. There are a number of mechanisms for creating a new UserManager when you need one. Create one, use a singleton (which I don't like). Inversion of Control, some form of static or a context object.

Answer (score 0):

It's not to do with renaming, because if you rename the interface method it would still break the clients.

For me, the best thing about interfaces is that you can mock them really easily. You cannot do that with a real class.

i.e. Let's say you wanted to unit test a method that creates a new user. e.g. `CreateNewUser()` creates a new `User` object, and calls `Register` on it.

With interfaces, you could mock the `User` object and force its fake `Register` method to return a value that means something to your test. i.e:

```
//arrange
var u = new Mock<IUser>;
u.Setup(x => x.Register()).Returns(true);

//act
var newUser = CreateNewUser();

//assert
Assert.IsNotNull(newUser);
```

You can make another test for when `Register` returns false, and so on.

Without using interfaces, how would your unit tests look?

Answer (score 0):

One of the principal in software development is to keep the different system loosely couple . Using the interface in the current context help you to do the same. For example in case you have IUser as interface you can use in the client code any class which implements the IUser interface.

```
     public class RegisterClass{
         private IUser _user;              
         public RegisterClass(IUser user){
           _user = user;
         };

         public void Validate(){
         //you can validate the IUser.
         }
      }

    public class UserOne : IUser {
    }

    public class UserTwo : IUser {
    }
```

Now the flexibility comes that any concrete class with IUser as interface can be used.